# Why is this function in $W^{1,p}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This is an example from Evans book. Let $X=B^n(0,1)$, the n-dimensional unit ball.I know that the function $|x|^{-\alpha}$ is in $W^{1,p}(X)$ if and only if $\alpha<\frac{n-p}{p}$.

> Now let $(x_j)_j$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. Define $u(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}|x-x_j|^{-\alpha}$. Then $u\in W^{1,p}(X)$ if and only if $\alpha<\frac{n-p}{p}$ Since 
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}||\frac{1}{2^j}|x-x_j|^{-\alpha}||_{1,p}&\le
> \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}|||x-x_j|^{-\alpha}||_{1,p}\\
> &=|||x|^{-\alpha}||_{1,p}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}\\
> &=|||x|^{-\alpha}||_{1,p}
> \end{align}

But I don't see why the third equality is true. That is, why is $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}|||x-x_j|^{-\alpha}||_{1,p}=|||x|^{-\alpha}||_{1,p}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}$? Can someone please explain.

Comment: This is hard to read and understand because you have used $n$ to refer both to the dimension of the space and the index of the sequence.

Comment: @Jason good point, I'll change it

Comment: We don't have equality, but an inequality ($\lVert \lvert x-x_j\rvert^{-\alpha}\rVert_{1,p} \leqslant \lVert \lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha}\rVert_{1,p}$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm afraid I don't see this either. We'd have to show $|| \ |x-x_j|^{-\alpha} \ ||_p+|| \ |D|x-x_j|^{-\alpha} \ ||_p\leq|| \ |x|^{-\alpha} \ ||_p+|| \ |D|x|^{-\alpha} \ ||_p$, but this isn't apparent to me either

Comment: Think of it keeping the function - $\lvert x\rvert^{-\alpha}$ - fixed and moving the ball. When you move the ball, the function takes smaller values on the part coming into the ball than on the part going out. The same for the derivatives.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, ok that makes. Thanks Daniel

Comment: The inequality would be easier to understand if it would be estimated against $\|\,|\cdot|^{-\alpha}\,\|_{W^{1,p}(B^n(0,2)}$, ie, taking the norm on a larger ball.